# Windows Battery Report shows use before purchasing

Tags: battery-life, microsoft-surface

I bought Microsoft Surface Book 512GB i7 16GB with original packaging but not from the store directly. The previous owner claimed its brand new and looks like one.

I generated Battery Report using : powercfg /batteryreport /output

The laptop was bought a week ago, yet I see on Battery report about 40 items spanning from 2016-07-22 over the course of months. Those items do not have timing info, but there are dates. This worries me the laptop is not new.

Can we reliably depend on the Battery Report, its quite hard to clear the stats so I would assume if there was some previous use maybe it was not easy to wipe out.

Another hypothesis is that maybe every laptop even bought from Microsoft directly has this and its just part of the QA Microsoft does before releases models for sale?

Comment: Sounds like the laptop isn't new, July 2016 is around the time, the Surface book was released

Comment: "On October 26, 2016, Microsoft announced an updated Surface Book with a new Nvidia GeForce GTX 965M GPU and additional battery life over the original model." So first verify you have the 965M, but even if you do, still could be used so check the health of the SSD.  You can check to see how many hours it's been turned on.  It's entirely possible, the battery status before Oct, is the OEM history